# Flickering UIView in Simulator running from a Playground

Tags: xcode, swift, swift-playground, xcplayground

I'm running a playground, Xcode 6.3 (6D543q). Therefore Swift 1.2

The Playground imports XCPlayground.
I'm creating a UIView and calling XCPShowView() to have it render in the Simulator instead of in the Playground.
I'm also presenting a UIAlertView the same way.

The UIAlertView appears as normal.
The UIView flickers between a larger and smaller size about 5 times a second, reasonable irregularly. 
I've tried resizing it to meet the bounds of the screen but no luck.

Code below....

```
// Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import UIKit
import Foundation
import XCPlayground

 XCPlayground.XCPSetExecutionShouldContinueIndefinitely(continueIndefinitely: true)

@objc class alertHandler: NSObject, UIAlertViewDelegate {

  func alertView(alertView: UIAlertView, clickedButtonAtIndex buttonIndex: Int) {
    if buttonIndex > 0 {

     // View things....
     let redRectangleFrame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 200, height: 200)
     let redRectangle = UIView(frame: redRectangleFrame)
     redRectangle.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
     redRectangle.setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints(false)
     XCPShowView("Red Rectangle", redRectangle)

     // Alert view things...
     let recevingAlertView = alertView

     let text = alertView.textFieldAtIndex(0)?.text
     println("\(text!)")
     println("Button \(buttonIndex)")
    }
  }
}

let anAlertHandler = alertHandler()

let status = "Hey there!"
let message = "Do you have a moment to talk about our Lord and Saviour, Cthulhu?"
let cancel = "Sounds wierd"
let ok = "Oooh! Yes"

let alert = UIAlertView(title: status,
                  message: message,
                 delegate: anAlertHandler,
        cancelButtonTitle: cancel,
        otherButtonTitles: ok)
alert.alertViewStyle = UIAlertViewStyle.PlainTextInput
alert.show()

XCPShowView("Alert", alert)
```

Comment: Greetings from NSCoder Night. Drunk. Can't read. Sorry.

Comment: OK, I filed a Radar: 20256369

Comment: any luck? I see the same with a UIScrollView.

Comment: Nothing yet I'm afraid, hoping to take it to the labs in WWDC

Answer (score 1):

Noticed some flicker locally with a few test playground simulator examples (your example was crashing for me Version 6.3.2 (6D2105))

From [this post](http://possiblemobile.com/2015/03/prototyping-uiview-animations-swift-playground/) (their animation did show up but was flickering, and overlapping)

> There are some limitations and draw backs to UIKit in Playgrounds. The
>   primary limitation is that Auto Layout has some issues when used in
>   Playgrounds. Some constraints will cause runtime exceptions in
>   addition to increased compile times. Hopefully future updates to Xcode
>   will resolve this. Another draw back is the performance of Playgrounds
>   when using XCPlayground. There can be delays as Xcode works with the
>   iOS Simulator running behind the Playground.